# Any C API or Perl Module to get the system info?

Tags: perl, sigar

I am looking for an API or perl module which collects the system architecute of different flavors of UNIX and Windows versons. Such as Unix Version, hardware, Number of CPU, Memory size etc. I am using SIGAR api to monitor the system resource, but it don't have any libraries that can collect system info. I am using perl bindings to call the SIGAR libraries.

Comment: did you find anything useful on CPAN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site you're looking for is http://search.cpan.org.  There you can search for modules and browse their documentation to see which best suits your needs.